# Use TaskExecutor with PublishSubscribeChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've got java spring boot configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public SubscribableChannel channel(MessageHandler handler) {
   PublishSubscribeChannel channel = new PublishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));
   channel.subscribe(handler);
   return channel;
}
```

My handler code:

```
@Service
public class SomeDataHandler implements MessageHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.print(message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

And some client code:

```
@Autowired
private SubscribableChannel channel
...
channel.send(...)
```

And it doesn't work. Just nothing happens.
But this configuration works fine for me:

```
@Bean
public SubscribableChannel channel(MessageHandler handler) {
   PublishSubscribeChannel channel = new PublishSubscribeChannel();
   channel.subscribe(handler);
   return channel;
}
```

So looks like I need to do something more to apply task executor to my channel. Any ideas? Thanks.

Spring integration version - 4.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"doesn't work" is not much to go on - show your executor and handler bean configurations.

Turn on DEBUG logging - it should help you figure out what's happening.

You should NOT be subscribing to the channel in the bean declaration; the handler will be subscribed automatically by the framework (if properly configured).

**EDIT**

You are not really using the framework as it was designed; when using an executor, the dispatcher is replaced during bean creation - overriding your subscription. You are subscribing too early in the bean lifecycle.

While not necessary, it's generally better to subclass `AbstractMessageHandler` and implement `handleMessageInternal` - then configure it like this...

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="channel")
@Bean
public MyAMHSubclass handler() {
    return new MyAMHSubclass();
}
```

and remove the `subscribe` from the channel bean declaration.

The `@ServiceActivator` wraps the handler in a consumer which subscribes to the channel when the context is initialized.

Comment: I've got debug log: 2016-06-27 19:14:27,304 22510 [qtp1567025476-18] DEBUG o.s.i.d.BroadcastingDispatcher - No subscribers, default behavior is ignore

Comment: See my edit; you are really not using the framework as it's designed - when using an executor, the default dispatcher is replaced during bean creation - overriding your subscription; you are subscribing too early in the bean lifecycle.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.